# CPU hits almost 100% with mogodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using mongoose library for mongodb with node js.

I have page which contains around 20 charts. All charts are related to same collection in mongo db.

I have to call almost 15-16 services for the charts on same collection.

When i do this cpu hits almost 100% with MongoDB database server.

Can anyone suggest how to optimize this.

Below is log of mongodb queries.

```
2017-09-01T23:57:25.164+0000 I COMMAND  [conn4] command HyperlocalPortalDB.users command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { mac: “$mac” } } },
 { $lookup: { from: “users”, localField: “_id.mac”, foreignField: “mac”, as: “userDetail” } }, 
 { $match: { userDetail.activations.activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’) } }, 
 { $unwind: “$userDetail” }, { $project: { mac: “$_id.mac”, groupField: “$userDetail.city” } }, 
 { $group: { _id: “$groupField”, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
 { $sort: { count: -1 } } ] } 
 planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10810 nreturned:0 reslen:18599 
 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 26198 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 13099 } }, 
 Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 13098 } } } protocol:op_query 7755ms

2017-09-01T23:57:25.264+0000 I COMMAND  [conn3] command HyperlocalPortalDB.users command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { mac: “$mac” } } }, 
{ $lookup: { from: “users”, localField: “_id.mac”, foreignField: “mac”, as: “userDetail” } }, 
{ $match: { userDetail.activations.activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’) } }, 
{ $unwind: “$userDetail” }, { $project: { mac: “$_id.mac”, groupField: “$userDetail.country” } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$groupField”, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $sort: { count: -1 } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10831 nreturned:0 reslen:82 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 26240 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 13120 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 13119 } } } protocol:op_query 7776ms

2017-09-01T23:57:25.486+0000 I COMMAND  [conn5] command HyperlocalPortalDB.users command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { mac: “$mac” } } }, 
{ $lookup: { from: “users”, localField: “_id.mac”, foreignField: “mac”, as: “userDetail” } }, 
{ $match: { userDetail.activations.activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’) } }, 
{ $unwind: “$userDetail” }, { $project: { mac: “$_id.mac”, groupField: “$userDetail.state” } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$groupField”, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $sort: { count: -1 } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10806 nreturned:0 reslen:2053 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 26190 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 13095 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 13094 } } } protocol:op_query 7336ms

2017-09-01T23:57:25.564+0000 I COMMAND  [conn6] command HyperlocalPortalDB.users command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { mac: “$mac” } } }, 
{ $lookup: { from: “users”, localField: “_id.mac”, foreignField: “mac”, as: “userDetail” } }, 
{ $match: { userDetail.activations.activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’) } }, 
{ $unwind: “$userDetail” }, { $project: { mac: “$_id.mac”, groupField: “$userDetail.state” } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$groupField”, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $sort: { count: -1 } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10811 nreturned:0 reslen:2053 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 26200 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 13100 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 13099 } } } protocol:op_query 8259ms

2017-09-01T23:57:26.018+0000 I COMMAND  [conn2] command HyperlocalPortalDB.users command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { mac: “$mac” } } }, { $lookup: { from: “users”, localField: “_id.mac”, foreignField: “mac”, as: “userDetail” } }, 
{ $match: { userDetail.activations.activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’) } }, 
{ $unwind: “$userDetail” }, { $project: { mac: “$_id.mac”, groupField: “$userDetail.city” } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$groupField”, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $sort: { count: -1 } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10804 nreturned:0 reslen:18599 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 26186 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 13093 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 13092 } } } protocol:op_query 7978ms

2017-09-01T23:57:29.030+0000 I COMMAND  [conn5] command HyperlocalPortalDB.coordinates command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1503896340000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$mac”, minTime: { $min: “$t” }, maxTime: { $max: “$t” } } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 numYields:10751 nreturned:0 reslen:26423 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21538 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10769 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10768 } } } protocol:op_query 3537ms

2017-09-01T23:57:29.812+0000 I COMMAND  [conn3] command HyperlocalPortalDB.coordinates command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503982800000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$mac”, minTime: { $min: “$t” }, maxTime: { $max: “$t” } } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 numYields:10755 nreturned:0 reslen:25216 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21540 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10770 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10769 } } } protocol:op_query 4540ms

2017-09-01T23:57:30.641+0000 I COMMAND  [conn6] command HyperlocalPortalDB.coordinates command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503896400000), $lt: new Date(1503982740000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: “$mac”, minTime: { $min: “$t” }, maxTime: { $max: “$t” } } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 numYields:10762 nreturned:0 reslen:25145 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21558 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10779 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10778 } } } protocol:op_query 5077ms

2017-09-01T23:57:31.664+0000 I COMMAND  [conn2] command HyperlocalPortalDB.users command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { mac: “$mac” } } }, { $lookup: { from: “users”, localField: “_id.mac”, foreignField: “mac”, as: “userDetail” } }, 
{ $match: { userDetail.activations.activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’) } }, { $unwind: “$userDetail” }, 
{ $project: { mac: “$_id.mac”, groupField: “$userDetail.country” } }, { $group: { _id: “$groupField”, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
{ $sort: { count: -1 } } ] } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10774 nreturned:0 reslen:82 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 26126 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 13063 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 13062 } } } protocol:op_query 5638ms

2017-09-01T23:57:33.839+0000 I COMMAND  [conn5] warning: log line attempted (89kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... command HyperlocalPortalDB.coordinates command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, 
pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503810000000), $lt: new Date(1503896340000) }, mac: { $in: [ “41:9e:87:01:00:00", “41:9E:87:01:00:00”, “ab:cd:ed”, “41:9e:87:01:09:64”, “41:9E:87:01:09:64" ] } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { $dateToString: { format: “%Y-%m-%d %H”, date: { $subtract: [ “$t”, 14400000 ] } } },
 macList: { $addToSet: “$mac” } } },  { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ] } 
 planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10756 nreturned:0 reslen:80098 
 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21548 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10774 } }, 
 Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10773 } } } protocol:op_query 4433ms

2017-09-01T23:57:34.270+0000 I COMMAND  [conn6] warning: log line attempted (89kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... command HyperlocalPortalDB.coordinates command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503982800000), $lt: new Date(1504069140000) }, mac: { $in: [ “41:9e:87:01:00:00”, “41:9E:87:01:00:00", “ab:cd:ed”, “AB:CD:ED”,  “41:9e:87:01:09:64", “41:9E:87:01:09:64” ] } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { $dateToString: { format: “%Y-%m-%d %H”, date: { $subtract: [ “$t”, 14400000 ] } } }, 
macList: { $addToSet: “$mac” } } }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10749 nreturned:0 reslen:57332 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21528 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10764 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10763 } } } protocol:op_query 3619ms

2017-09-01T23:57:34.376+0000 I COMMAND  [conn4] warning: log line attempted (89kB) over max size (10kB), printing beginning and end ... command HyperlocalPortalDB.coordinates command: aggregate { aggregate: “coordinates”, pipeline: [ { $match: { activationId: ObjectId(‘59a6e4dad95d240cf4ba37de’), t: { $gte: new Date(1503896400000), $lt: new Date(1503982740000) }, mac: { $in: [ “41:9e:87:01:00:00", “41:9E:87:01:00:00”, “ab:cd:ed”, “AB:CD:ED”, “41:9e:87:01:09:64”, “41:9E:87:01:09:64" ] } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: { $dateToString: { format: “%Y-%m-%d %H”, date: { $subtract: [ “$t”, 14400000 ] } } }, macList: { $addToSet: “$mac” } } }, 
{ $sort: { _id: 1 } } ] } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1373500 hasSortStage:1 numYields:10758 nreturned:0 reslen:76210 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21550 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10775 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 10774 } } } protocol:op_query 4973ms
```

Comment: do you have an index on `activationId` field ?

Comment: I peeled back the really long comment because the problems listed are too many. How about showing what data you have and what you need as a result. Also explain how you acquire the data in the first place. You probably should be pre-aggregating any data that you gave high volume requests for anyway.

Comment: @felix `COLLSCAN` in the slow query log entries say NO. Index usage is just one of a multitude of problems apparent in the logged pipelines though.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I have pre-aggregated data that gives me high volume requests. In every queries you can see that i have used match statement on collection & then group by field to avoid fetching high volume data. Most of queries are first match on coordinates collection then group by mac & then join with user collection after that group by specific field of user collection.

Comment: Dude. You are "joining", and that's never efficient. It's just a stop gap. If you need performance, then all the data is in the one collection in minimal form. The operations here are far from optimal. Hence the suggestion to instead explain the data collection and the current available data and expected result. I could write a whole page on the problems in your present pipeline without necessarily doing everything possible to actually improve performance. So it might be academic, but it's not going to solve the general issue.

Comment: Check if the ideas from http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2016/7/4/join-performance-in-mongodb-32-using-lookup.html help

Comment: @NeilLunn, my issue is not "joining", queries works far better alone. My result is not possible without joins. It's two collection. It's creating issue when more than 10 queries hits db asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Disable console displays

2 - Apply mongodb [productions notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/).

For example:

> With the WiredTiger storage engine, use of XFS is strongly recommended to avoid performance issues that may occur when using EXT4 with WiredTiger.

---

> Disable Transparent Huge Pages. MongoDB performs better with normal (4096 bytes) virtual memory pages.

Comment: I have used mongodb 3.4, which uses WiredTiger storage engine. How to Disable Transparent Huge Pages?

Comment: You have to look at mongodb documentation. [Hugepage section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/)